# Storing UIImage for later use

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making what can be described as an image manipulation app. My idea is that the user imports `UIImage`s through the pod [YPImagePicker](https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker) and they are stored in two arrays, one for thumbnails and one for the fullsized images. A `UICollectionView` is then populated with the thumbnails and when the user taps the thumbnail the fullsized image is displayed in a `UIImageView`.

I am having memory issues with this solution. The RAM hits 300 MB on an iPhone X when I have roughly 10-12 images imported, which I have understood is too much. I guess it is because I store all the fullsized images in an array? Should I store the fullsized images on the users hard drive and not in RAM-memory? Or is there any way I can access the images from the users photo library and fetch the image when the user taps the thumbnail?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but if it's to allow the user to select various images from the device, save references to the selections in an array and load the images as-needed. As a side note, saying *"I'm using [this] library..."* can make it difficult to offer help. Review [ask] for future reference.

Comment: You should be using Apple's PHCachingImageManager https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/loading_and_caching_assets_and_thumbnails

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this space, both SO and programming in general. I see. Should I use the imagemanager mentioned by Josh and save the PHAssets in an array and then fetch the PHAsset from there when I want it to be displayed? Is the PHAsset object the reference you are talking about?